# WPF Slider override ValueProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I am playing an audiofile. The position of the current track gets displayed by a silder. The value of the slider is bound to a property which gets updated every 40ms. The problem is, that when the user drages the thumb of the slider, the position gets updated again(of the timer every 40ms). As a result, the user is not able to change the thumb. I would like to create a slider which does not update his value property while the user is dragging the thumb.

I've tried something like this:

```
public class SliderDragPriority : Slider
{
    bool allowvaluechange = true;

    protected override void OnValueChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
    {
        if (allowvaluechange)
            base.OnValueChanged(oldValue, newValue);
        //else -> don't change value
    }

    protected override void OnThumbDragDelta(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnThumbDragStarted(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnThumbDragStarted(e);
        allowvaluechange = false;
    }

    protected override void OnThumbDragCompleted(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        allowvaluechange = true;
        base.OnThumbDragCompleted(e);
    }
}
```

The problem of the code is, that the OnValueChanged does not affect the value property.

Comment: `OnValueChanged` is just a convenience method that is called *after the value has already been changed*. `base.OnValueChanged` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Hence this approach won't work. You may however consider to create another value property (say `MyValue`) which behaves as desired. That property would only be updated according to the current `Value` when `allowvaluechange` is `true`.